# Can I restructure the folder in CodeIgniter app?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have changed my CodeIgniter app folder structure like below:

MyCodeIgniterApp
 - application
 - system
 - newsubfolder
     -  public
     -  index.php
     -  .htaccess
     -  composer.json

As you can see above folder structure, I have kept the public,index.php and .htaccess file inside the subfolder. And I have changed the application and system path inside the index.php file to use right one.
My question is can I access my app like http://localhost/MyCodeIgniterApp or what else should I do in order to access like that?

Comment: Please, see this: https://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/moving-application-system-folder-safety/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using XAMPP on windows

I would recommend you having the folder structure as below

```
   MyCodeIgniterApp
    - application
    - system
    - composer.json
    - public
        - assets
        - index.php
        - .htaccess
```

But if you want to keep the folder structure same, then just change the paths so as they are pointing to the same files as the following code

1. First change the index.php's system and application folder's path settings

from

```
    $system_path = 'system';
    $application_folder = 'application';
```

to

```
    $system_path = '../system';
    $application_folder = '../application';
```

2. Add another .htaccess in your Application in the same folder as system and application
   this is done to block apache's access to this folder (because we only need the php to communicate to this folder)

.htaccess

```
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !authz_core_module>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
```

3. Modify the .htaccess in the public folder to

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   ```

Now you need to configure the Apache server to serve the public folder rather than htdocs
You can achieve this modifying the httpd.conf settings
from

```
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

to

```
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyCodeIgniterApp/public"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyCodeIgniterApp/public">
```

but doing so you will loose your access to your other applications in your htdocs folder
To avoid this try setting a virtual domain to your new application

4. Change to your XAMPP installation directory (typically, C:\xampp) and open the httpd-vhosts.conf file in the apache\conf\extra\ subdirectory using your favourite text editor.(as admin)
   and add a new virtual host config to httpd-vhosts.conf

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost app.local:80>   
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyCodeIgniterApp/public"
    ServerName app.local
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyCodeIgniterApp/public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

here 'app.local' is your required virtual domain

Now open the file 'C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' as admin
and add

```
    127.0.0.1         app.local
```

5. RESTART XAMPP and try going to your new virtual domain
   e.g http://app.local

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer for my query. Much appreciated. I have done all of the steps you mentioned an finally ping to http://app.local, but it says "This site can’t be reached app.local’s server IP address could not be found.". Actually the port used in the httpd.conf file is 8080 so I used that in httpd-vhosts.conf file. Should I do anything else to make working this? But it worked when I gave my app's public path to httpd.conf document root

Comment: @RajeeshThayyullathil I have updated the answer, missed the windows URL mapping configuration

Comment: It is still not working :( 
I have added the line '127.0.0.1         app.local' in host file.

Comment: :@ZEN-Oh-sama  
I am sorry.. It worked when I pinged http://app.local:8080
Thanks a lot for your wonderful help.